# Is it possible to display more than one item in a cell with a foreach condition?

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3, database-design

[image: What I have & what I would like]

I think it's more easier to visualise with picture than I explain what I want. **There is any way to have a table looks like the second one on the picture?** Now I've the first, but the problem that I have is that my table is populate dynamically like this :

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.OrderDetail>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>

        <td align="center">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrderId)
        </td>

        <td>
         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Order.Username)          
        </td>
        <td>
         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Order.ClientID)          
        </td>

        <td>
         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Order.SiteNumber)          
        </td>   

        <td>
           @{
            if (item.Pack == null)
            {
                   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.Name) 
            }
            else
            {
                 <text>Pack</text>
                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pack.Name)
            }
            }    
        </td>

        <td>
            @if (item.Pack == null)
            {
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UnitPrice)
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UnitPricePack)
            }
        </td>

        <td align="center">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Order.Total)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Order.OrderDate)
        </td>
    </tr>  
    .....
```

I found nothing on the internet about that except Interface, but it seems a bit complicated at my level, and I must change all my code if I use it.  An idea ? I take all advices, thank you for your help

Here are my models :

OrderDetails

```
 public class OrderDetail
    {
        public int OrderDetailId { get; set; }
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int PackId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        [Range(0.00, 100000.00)]
        public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }

        [Range(0.00, 100000.00)]
        public decimal UnitPricePack { get; set; }


        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
        public virtual Pack Pack { get; set; }
        public virtual Order Order { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Pack> Packs { get; set; }
    }
```

Product

```
 public class Product
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int      ProductId   { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Pack")]
        public int      PackId      { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="blabla")]
        [StringLength(160)]
        [DisplayName("Nom")]
        public string   Name        { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Description")]
        [StringLength(200)]
        public string   Description { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="blabla")]
        [Range(0.00, 10000.00, ErrorMessage="blabla")]
        [DisplayName("Prix")]
        public decimal   Price       { get; set; }

        public virtual Pack     Pack  { get; set; }

        public virtual List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

and my Pack model

```
 public class Pack
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int      PackId      { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("blabla")]
        public string   Name        { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("blabla")]
        public string   Description { get; set; }


        [Required(ErrorMessage="blabla")]
        [Range(0.00, 10000.00, ErrorMessage="blabla")]
        [DisplayName("Prix")]
        public decimal  Price { get; set; }

        public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public virtual List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a ViewModel like this

```
public class OrderViewModel
{
  public int OrderID { set;get;}
  public string UserName { set;get;}
  public int UserID { set;get;}
  public List<OrderItem> Products { set;get;}
  public decimal OrderTotal { set;get;}
}

public class OrderItem
{
  public string ProductID { set;get;}
  public string ProductName { set;get;}
  public decimal UnitPrice { set;get;}
  public int Quantity { set;get;}
}
```

Now in your view

```
@model List<OrderViewModel>
@foreach(var order in Model)
{
  <tr>
     <td>@order.OrderID</td>
     <td>@order.UserName</td>
     <td>
        <ul>
        @foreach(var item in order.Products)
        {
          <li>@item.ProductName</li> 
        }
        </ul>
     </td>
     <td>
        <ul>
        @foreach(var item in order.Products)
        {
          <li>@item.Quantity</li> 
        }
        </ul>
     </td>
     <td>
        <ul>
        @foreach(var item in order.Products)
        {
          <li>@item.UnitPrice</li> 
        }
        </ul>
     </td>
     <td> 
         @order.OrderTotal
     </td>
 </tr>    
}
```

Comment: I tried some things, but always have an error CS1061 or CS1579

Comment: At this moment, I have another error. Column name is not valid [ Node name (if any) = Extent1,Column name = Pack_PackId ]. This is for the first foreach: @foreach (var item in Model).

Comment: My View code is for the ViewModel i defined. It looks like you are using a different Model (possibliy the same domain model form your entity framework). Create a viewmodel and map your domain model value to that and use that in your view.

Comment: I must redefine all my data that I define in my Models in a single ViewModel ? Or do something like that : define in this ViewModel some `public List<OrderDetails> ODetails (get set)     //    public List<Product> Prod (get set)    //  List<Pack> Pack (get set)`.   It's a bit fuzzy

Comment: ViewModel should have those properties which the View really needs. Not all properties in your Domain model.

Comment: I can not give a specific answer to that question as i am not sure what Pack meant for. Think logically and you will be able to make a decision. Also do not ask questions in comment section. Post as a new question with relevant details

Comment: ok thanks for your help, I've not been able to make it works yet but I still dig and try all I can. Pack contains product, several products can be in one pack, and some products could be in none pack.

Comment: Damn, whatever I'm doing returns me this error 

'type' does not contain a definition for 'member' and no extension method 'name' accepting a first argument of type 'type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).