# How to set a Viewmodel from several Models?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, database-design, mvvm, ado.net

I would like to retrieve several items in one cell of a table in my view. I have several models, Product, Pack(as category), Order and OrderDetail. I think to achieve what I want, I should create a view model with data from my Models, but I don't really know how to do this and wich data i should bind.

This my view

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrderId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Username)          
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClientID)          
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SiteNumber)
        </td>   
        <td>
            @if (item.Pack == null)
            {
                    <ul>
                        @foreach (var tmp in item.????) //PRODUCT
                        { 
                           <li>Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => tmp.Name) </li>
                        } 
                    </ul>
            }
            else
            {                 
                    <ul>
                        @foreach (var tmp in item.????) //PACK
                        { 
                            <li>Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => tmp.Name) </li> 
                        } 
                    </ul>                       
            }
        </td>

        <td>
        @{
                if (item.Pack == null)
                {
                        <ul>
                            @foreach (var tmp in item.????)  // PRODUCT
                            { 
                                <li>Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => tmp.UnitPrice)
                               </li>
                            }
                        </ul>
                }
                else
                {                    
                        <ul>
                                @foreach (var tmp in item.????) //PACK
                                { 
                                    <li>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => tmp.UnitPricePack)
                                    </li>
                                }
                        </ul>
                }
}

        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Total)
        </td>        
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrderDate)
        </td>
    </tr>
```

I would like my table looks like that at the end :

[image]

My question again, How can I create a ViewModel to retrieves data in my view and for it match with my @foreach condition inside ma table... I don't know if I am clear enough... This post follow [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282885/is-it-possible-to-display-more-than-one-item-in-a-cell-with-a-foreach-condition) . Actually, what i've done returns me error on error, I don't really know how to set up my viewmodel, which data I need to bind and how. Thanks for your help, your advices, I take all

Comment: what's the actual Model of your view ? an `IList<Order>` ?

Comment: in my view I call  @Model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.OrderDetail> for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a new ViewModel, Order has all you need. Your model will be a list of orders.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrderId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Username)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClientID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SiteNumber)
        </td>
        <td>
            <ul>
                @foreach (var o in item.OrderDetails)
                {

                    if (o.Pack == null)
                    {
                    <li>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => o.Product.Name) </li> //PRODUCT
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    <li>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => o.Pack.Name) </li> // PACK

                    }
                }
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
                <ul>
                    @foreach (var o in item.OrderDetails)
                    {

                        if (o.Pack == null)
                        {
                        <li>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => o.UnitPrice) </li> //PRODUCT
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        <li>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => o.UnitPricePack) </li>  //PACK
                        }
                    }
                </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
            <ul>
                @foreach (var o in item.OrderDetails)
                {
                    <li>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => o.Quantity)</li>
                }
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Total)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrderDate)
        </td>
    </tr>  
}
```

**Update according to your update:**

You are still trying to pass collection of orderdetails instead of orders

instead of this:

```
        var user = from m in db.OrderDetails
                   select m;
```

Have this ( assuming you have Orders table):

```
    public ActionResult Index(string searchSite, string searchString)
    {

        var user = from m in db.Orders
                   select m;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            user = user.Where(s => s.ClientID.Contains(searchString));                
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchSite))
        {
            user = user.Where(c => c.SiteNumber.Contains(searchSite));
        }
            return View(user);
    }
```

Comment: I called @model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.Order>  instead of OrderDetail that's right ?

Comment: That's right, there's something wrong with your controller action. Looks like you are still querying orderdetails from database and passing it to the view instead of orders.

Comment: I'l try to change my OrderDetails calls to Orders, but noting change, I'll edit my post to upload my controller. But I've just a method who provide a search by string.

Comment: Yes I know ! :)  But i told you, even in doing that, change OrderDetails by Orders, it doesn't change anything, same error

Comment: No sorry, i've this error : System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
for the line  @foreach (var o in item.OrderDetails)   & yes I have a table for each Model i've wrote

Comment: Then your Order doesn't have any OrderDetails. Check for null before the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest use of [`AutoMapper'](http://automapper.codeplex.com/), you can try

```
public class A{
 public string FirstName{get;set;}
}

public class B{
public string LastName{get;set;}
}
```

now create a view mode

```
public class VModel{
public string FirstName{get;set;}
public string LastName{get;set;}
}
```

and where you want them to converge use auto mapper like

```
Mapper.CreateMap<A,VModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<B,VModel>();

var ObjectOfClassA= new A{FirstName="John"};
var ObjectOfClassB= new A{LastName="Smith"};

VModel _model = Mapper.Map<A,VModel>(ObjectOfClassA);
_model = Mapper.Map<B,VModel>(ObjectOfClassB);
```

access it like

```
_model.FirstName;//should give you john
_model.LastName;//should give you smith
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like not to use an extern library, my app may be modify by someone else in the futur. But in last case I'll try it, and it could be usefull for me in time so thanks anyway for that, I didn't know this tool